# How can you change the height of an x-axis with d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

When I add an x-axis to our chart and set the range of its scale exactly to **[0 - chart.width]** and if you use this css:

```
.x-axis path {
    fill: none;
}
```

you can see little lines on the left and on the right edge of the axis.

[image]

This is because the `<path>` element still has a height, which you would alter with its [d-attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#DAttribute). Does anybody know an options to change the height of the axis with **d3**?

In the HTML it looks like this:

```
<path class="domain" d="M-1,-6V0H1042V-6"></path>
```

---

I can (and do this right now) change the range of the scale of the axis, but this (taken seriously) changes the positions of the ticks, too. So my last option would be a rude HTML/SVG-hack. Any advices? Do I miss something in the d3 axis-API?

---

If you are interested in the JS, I can post the method, which creates the axis, the whole chart is managed with almost 800 lines.

```
/*
  chartAttrs is an object, which holds some important
  values/attributes of the chart (like its width,
  height, svgRoot and similar chart elements).
*/
var createXAxis = function() {
  if (chartAttrs.width) {
    if (!_.isObject(chartAttrs.xAxis)) {
      chartAttrs.xAxis = {};
    }
    chartAttrs.xAxis.scale = d3.time.scale() //most important here: we use d3 time scale
      .domain(createTimeAxisDomain(false))
      //createTimeAxisDomain creates an array with two date objects (new Date([some_timestamp]))
      .range([-1, chartAttrs.width + 2]);
    chartAttrs.xAxis.axisMeth = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(chartAttrs.xAxis.scale)
      .orient('top');
    chartAttrs.xAxis.axis = chartAttrs.d3Root.append('g')
      .attr({ 
        'class': 'x-axis',
        'transform': 'translate(0,' + (chartAttrs.height - (chartAttrs.margins.bottom * 3)) + ')' //bad magic number
      })
      .call(chartAttrs.xAxis.axisMeth/*
        .innerTickSize([10])
        .outerTickSize([10])*/);
  } else {
    $log.warn("No chartAttrs.width -> no x axis!", chartAttrs); //AngularJS stuff
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you post the JS that is generating the chart?

Comment: @spanndemic done, I hope, this is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`axis.tickSize()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#tickSize) function for this, in particular `.tickSize([0,0])` to have no ticks.

`.tickSize([])` brings a slightly different result, it leaves minimal space between the axis line and the `<text>` elements of the ticks.

You can also control the size of the end "ticks" separately with `.outerTickSize()`.

Comment: Yup, this worked. But I used `.tickSize([])` A minimal example can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/MalteFab/6vy06ggx/